# HDR implementation in AVCaptureSession

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, uikit, ios7, avcapturesession

Is there a convenient way to use HDR photo capture in iOS 6 or iOS 7 while capturing image using `AVCaptureSession`? I've searched through StackOverflow and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this feature? I want to implement this in iOS 8.0 or abovr

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly, this feature is not exposed by the APIs currently. The only way would be to use the `UIImagePickerController` but it's probably not what you want.